# Using move semantics and perfect forwarding to implement a 'lazy' operator+

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

I am trying to write a

```
friend T operator+( lhs, rhs){
};
```

Now, I would like to avoid construction of temporaries when possible.

For example:

1. If both `lhs`  and `rhs` are `const T&` the `operator+` should create a `temp` copy-constructing from `lhs`, then `temp += rhs;`  to it and finally `return std::move(temp)`.
2. If `lhs` is `T&&` then I want to directly sum `rhs` to it as in `lhs += rhs;` and then `return std::move(lhs)`. This case avoid a copy-construction in `(A+B)+C` since the output of `(A+B)` is not needed outside the expression. Notice that we might have to do `temp(std::move(lhs))` to have a common code for both Case 1. and Case 2.
3. Similarly for the other two case when either `rhs` or both `lhs` and `rhs` are `T&&`.

By writing four overloads I have managed to do this. Now, I have read that it is possible to take advantage of templates and `forward` to reduce the number of overloads or maybe even write it in just one template function. I am having trouble understanding how.

It seems to be that I need

```
template<typename R, typename S, typename T>
R operator+(S&& lhs, T&& rhs){
   // ...
};
```

But what I have tried for the content doesn't work.

There is an additional issue that I might have to deal with. If instead of `operator+` we need `operator-` or `operator/` the body of the method it not necessarily similar in all the cases. In `A/B`, if `A` is `T&&` we can `A /= B`. But if `B` is the one that is `T&&` then we might need to do `B.reciprocal() *= A`. So, I think I also need a way to know which case was entered in the template.

**Note:** My multiplication **IS** commutative (component-wise multiplication in matrices).

Could you give some comments and ideas on how to approach this problem?

**Note to self and to the next reader:** A [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Expression-template) to some reading on the use of expression templates.

Comment: I think for true lazy-evaluation you're going to have to use expression templates.

Comment: I'm not sure if this level of generality is warranted. Move semantics is about heavy, resource-owning objects. Division and subtraction are about numbers.

Comment: @KerrekSB Use some abstraction. I never said that `A,B,C` were numbers. In my case they are actually matrices, and they will be big matrices.

Comment: @Rapptz Maybe you are saying something that is going to be useful to me, but before I jump to read about expression templates let me understand what you mean by *true lazy-evaluation*. My goal is *only* to avoid the copy-constructions that can be avoided. I am not sure how *true* is this level of laziness. For this goal, do you think I will need to learn about expression templates?

Comment: If your operators are commutative, one could try to apply a technique for boilerplate reduction by reordering the arguments such that the first is always an rvalue: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14d811e4d7e9297b (but this increases the amount of moves necessary, since the rvalue is potentially created within one function and therefore has to be moved out).

Comment: @dyp This can help reduce my 4+4=8 overloads for `operator+` and `operator*` (my operator* is component-wise and therefore commutative) down to 6 methods. It is some reduction at least.

Comment: Couple notes: `return temp;` will move, you don't need `return std::move(temp);` (unless the return variable is an lvalue reference, and then you probably shouldn't be trying to move it).  You've already noted that commutativity doesn't apply to all operators... for matrices it doesn't even apply to `*`.  Matrix multiplication and division results may not be the same size as either operand, so reusing the operand isn't possible.  Even for square matrices, `operator*=` is implemented in terms of `*` then `=`, because the left-hand side is needed repeatedly during the computation.

Comment: Oh, you're doing arithmetic on a valarray-like type, not a matrix.  Adjust above advice appropriately.

Comment: @Karene Do you count `recycle_any_and_apply` as a "method" here, or are there multiple types involved?

Comment: @dyp Yes, I was counting them. Shouldn't I? 4 `recycle_any_and_apply`, 1 `operator+` and 1 `operator*`.

Comment: @Karene: when dealing with operations on large matrices, it pays off to not traverse the matrices multiple times as this destroys cache locality. The approach Rapptz is referring to essentially builds up an expression tree from the actual expression which is evaluated upon assigning the result. In the simplest case of a sequence of additions, each array element is just read once and the result is just written once plus holding one value on the stack. With your "lazy" evaluation a temporary results is written once per operation.

Comment: @Karene I just wasn't sure what you're counting ;) To me, `recycle_and_apply` is some kind of library function (or rather, a sketch of a library function), since it can be reused for (m)any type(s) and (m)any commutative operator(s).

Comment: It'd be really nice if you post a test suite: show a list of expressions using this operator `+` for which you want to minimize copies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function named `sum`.  `sum` has 3 overloads: `lhs&&, rhs const&` and `lhs const&, rhs&&, ...` -- the `...` is important, as it makes it the worst match, removing ambiguity.  And finally `const& lhs, const& rhs`.

Then `template<lhs, rhs> auto operator+(lhs&&,rhs&&)->decltype` perfect forwards to `sum`.

Once you get that working we can move on.  We can either reimplement it for each operator, or move up a level of abstraction.

You have a mutating binary op (`+=` etc) and an anti-symmetric transformation (noop for most, inverse for divide -- the binary op for divide is `*=` btw).  Pass those to a dispatcher overloaded like `sum`.

Use function objects for those two, and rewriting the `sum` functions to take `increase_mat{}` and `noop{}` should be easy.

Comment: Your answer has been seen. Wrapping my head around it now.

Comment: @dyp what extra move?  `std::move` does not move, and neither does returning?  Only binding to values after moving... Ah I see: the `const&` gets moved without needing to?

Comment: @dyp the binary operator is `+=` not `+`.

Comment: I think this was a particularity of my approach. If you rely on side-effects, you won't have this issue (and it's not really an issue anyway). Nevermind.